# Que system for window console rdp sessions

Tags: windows

I'm currently working in a company where many of us log onto hosts/servers via Windows console session.

If one person is logged on and another tries it causes the person who was logged on first (and maybe doing something important) to be cut off.

Is there such a thing as an application for such events where before logging on people can see if any other IP address is controlling the host/server?

Also, if the person on the console session had the ability to leave a note for anybody thinking of taking over the session of when they are finished etc.. I have many other ideas for such things but could someone tell me if such an application exists?

Comment: Why are you logging into the servers directly and not using remote management tools?  Why would it cut people off, unless you are sharing an account?  There is very few normal tasks that you actually need to perform from the console session.

Comment: Well we  log on via remote desktop connection.. Is this what you mean?? See we must log on to view packets that are delivered to the host.etc,.

Comment: Well I am suggesting that you should encourage people to not RDP to a server unless they really must.  If they can perform a task using power shell remoting, psexec, running the MMC tools from a remote machine, then they should.  With all the remote admin functionality available, I hardly ever need to actually login to a console.

Answer (score 1):

check that people do not use the /console or /admin switch on the RDP client.

For servers, you can have up to 3 connections at same time (using different login). 2 normal and one with /admin or /console.

On 2008, they won't be logged of, just disconnected, so not loosing works

For workstation, no way, it's only one account

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called Terminal Services Manager (W2K3 and W2K8) or Remote Desktop Services Manager (W2K8R2).